# Pandas can not write csv with CP1252 encoding

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, encoding, cp1252

I am trying to import a csv file in https://shop.deutschepost.de/. A demo csv file is given and both has the same encoding. But in my csv some character (German umlaut) is broken. The code I used to find my csv's encoding

```
file = r'/demo_briefe_mit_Adresse.csv'
with open(file) as f:
    print(f)
```

It gives output similar to

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/demo_briefe_mit_Adresse.csv' mode='r'
>   encoding='cp1252'>

Here is the demo file:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IsuBj2UaKivOCLOLh-cNx5_6MUmg_b0G/view?usp=sharing

Here is my output:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m1HqTbt6OMkKFJackmN9edBACBfrIREI/view?usp=sharing

Any debugging idea would be nice. Is pandas to_csv good for writing file or should I use some other method?

Comment: What is your problem? Your file is `cp1252` encoded. If you provide this info explicitly like `with open(file, encoding = "cp1252") as f:` or `df = pd.read_csv("demo_briefe_mit_Adresse.csv", encoding="cp1252", sep=";")` or `df.to_csv("demo.csv", encoding="cp1252")` you should have no problems with dealing with umlauts. Show us the full code snippet where you lose umlauts.

Comment: BTW, both the files you provided links to have umlauts displaying properly.

Comment: [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bUCDaevDKXx31uEdult-BPWv_CMx1nOR?usp=sharing) you will find additional info. Hope this gives a better view  Thanks!